# Choosing Between 2 games in one code

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am doing a project to make a user login, then ask the user to select which game to play, then write the code for the game. I have done everything apart from being able to choose to between the 2 games. Any tips on how to do this would greatly help!

```
 import java.io.*;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner; 
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class SkillsDemo31 {
private static boolean again = true;
private static int action;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //***************************
    //Login
    //***************************

    class User {
        User (String username, String password)
        {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        String GetUsername() {return username;}
        String GetPassword() {return password;}

        private String username;
        private String password;
    }


    String greeting = "Hello";
    String username;
    String password;

    // Used to hold the instance of a user who successfully logged in
    User loggedInUser = null;

    // Create an empty list to hold users
    List<User> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add 3 users to the list
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Gerry","spintown"));
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Evelyn","poker"));
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Joan","bonus"));


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    System.out.println("*** Welcome to the program ***\n");
    System.out.println(greeting);

    System.out.println("Please type your username :");
    username = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Please type your password :");
    password = br.readLine();

    for (User user : listOfUsers)
    {
        if (user.GetUsername().equals(username))
        {
            if (user.GetPassword().equals(password))
            {
                loggedInUser = user;
                // when a user is found, "break" stops iterating through the list
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // if loggedInUser was changed from null, it was successful
    if (loggedInUser != null)
    {
        System.out.println("User successfully logged in: "+loggedInUser.GetUsername());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid username/password combination");
    }

    //**********************************
    //Choice of Games
    //**********************************
    again = true;
    action = 0;

    while (again)
    {
        System.out.println("Please type 1 for Rock, Paper, Scissors or 2 for Play pick up sticks:");
        action = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (action == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to play Rock, Paper, Scissors");
        }
        else if (action == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to Play pick up sticks");
            again = false;
        }


        //******************************
        //Rock,Paper,Scissors
        //********************************




            Random rnd = new Random();
            int input;
            int score = 0;
            int B = 1;


            System.out.println("Pick 1,2, or 3 for:");
            System.out.println("Rock (1), Paper(2), or Scissors (3)");
            while (B != 0) {
                // 1 = rock
                // 2 = paper
                // 3 = scissors
                // N= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
                int Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissor = 3;

                input = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(3 - 1 + 1) + 1;
                if (randomNumber == Rock) {
                    if (input == Rock) {
                        System.out.println("Rock Vs. Rock: Tie");
                    } else if (input == Paper) {
                        System.out.println("Paper Vs. Rock: You Win!");
                        System.out.println("Congratulations!");
                        score++;
                    } else if (input == Scissor) {
                        System.out.println("Scissors Vs. Rock: You Lose");
                    }
                } else if (randomNumber == Paper) {
                    if (input == Rock) {
                        System.out.println("Rock Vs. Paper: You Loose");
                    } else if (input == Paper) {
                        System.out.println("Paper Vs. Paper: Tie");
                    } else if (input == Scissor) {
                        System.out.println("Scissors Vs. Paper: You Win");
                        System.out.println("Congratulations!");
                        score++;
                    }

                } else if (randomNumber == Scissor) {
                    if (input == Rock) {
                        System.out.println("Rock Vs. Scissors: You Win");
                        System.out.println("Congratulations!");
                        score++;
                    } else if (input == Paper) {
                        System.out.println("Paper Vs. Scissors: You Loose");
                    } else if (input == Scissor) {
                        System.out.println("Scissors Vs. Scissors: Tie");
                    }

                }

        int Y=5, N=10;
        System.out.println("Your score is "+ score);
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Press(5) For Yes/(10) For No");
        input = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(input==Y){
          B=1;  
          System.out.println("Rock, Paper,Scissors");
        }
        else if(input==N)
        {System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("Have A Good Day!");
            }

        //***********************
        //Pick Up Sticks
        //***********************



       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            int numSticks = 21;
             System.out.println("Would You Like to go first? (Yes/No)");
             Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
             String goFirst = input1.nextLine();
             Scanner take = new Scanner (System.in);
             int numToTake = 0;
             int score2 = 0;




             while (numSticks > 0) {


               if (goFirst.equals("Yes") || goFirst.equals("yes")) {
                 System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
                 System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
                 numToTake = take.nextInt();

                 if (numToTake > 2) {
                   numToTake = 2;

                 }

                 else if (numToTake < 1) {
                   numToTake = 1;
                 }
                 numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                 if (numSticks <= 0) {
                   System.out.println("You lose");
                   System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
                 }
                 else {

                   if((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
                     numToTake = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                     numToTake = 2;
                   }
                   System.out.println("Computer takes " + numToTake + " sticks " );
                   numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                   if (numSticks <= 0) {
                     System.out.println(" You win ");
                     score++;
                     System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
                   }
                 }

              }
              else {
                     if((numSticks - 2) % 3 == 0 || numSticks - 2 == 0) {
                     numToTake = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                     numToTake = 2;
                   } 
                   System.out.println("Computer takes " + numToTake + " sticks " );
                   numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                   if (numSticks <= 0) {
                     System.out.println("You win");
                     score++;
                     System.out.println("Your score is " + score );
                   }
                   else {
                       System.out.println("There are " + numSticks + " sticks ");
                       System.out.println("How many sticks do you want to take (1 or 2)");
                       numToTake = take.nextInt();

                       if (numToTake > 2) {
                           numToTake = 2;
                       }
                       else if (numToTake < 1){
                           numToTake = 1;
                       }
                       numSticks = numSticks - numToTake;

                       if(numSticks <0){
                           System.out.println("You win");
                           score++;


                       }




                       }

                    }



        }


           System.out.println("Do you want to play again, type (5) for yes or (10) for no");

              if (scanner.nextLine().equals("10")) {
                  break;
                   }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create for every game a class and create a start method there to start the game based on your user input for example:

```
            System.out.println("Please type 1 for game 1 or 2 for game2:");
            action = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if (action == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to game 1");
                Game1 game1 = new Game1();
                game1.start();
            }
            else if (action == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("\nYou have chosen game 2");
                Game2 game2 = new Game2();
                game2.start();
            }
```

This code is based on your code.

Comment: The both of you that commented are basically the same so I dont no how to thank for solution

Answer (score 0):

Bob, I just check through your code.

According to what I saw, my understanding of your question is that "After user login and selected the game type, both game would run subsequently, while you only want to run the game user chose".

If that is the case, then the solution is easy:

1. Take the games code parts out from the

   while(again){
     // In this block, only keeps your user choice code.
   }
   block. That block would be just for getting user's choice.
2. After that choice block, you get your users' choice from variable "action".  Now you just need to add a if block as below:

   if(action == 1){
     // Put your Rock,Paper,Scissors game code here, as user chose 1
     //******************************
     //Rock,Paper,Scissors
     //********************************
     ...
   }else if(action == 2){
     // Put your Pick Up Sticks game code here, as user chose 2. 
     //***********************
     //Pick Up Sticks
     //***********************
     ...
   }

As you only want to run one game at a time, you need a "IF" condition to tell the code which game to run. 
So just "IF" is enough, but separating the "Choice" part and "Game" part, from my opinion, would make the code more simpler and easier to be understood.

Comment: The both of you that commented are basically the same so I dont no how to thank for solution –